# How to do bulk lat/long lookup for google geocoding api in PHP?

Tags: php, json, google-maps-api-3, google-api, geocoding

I am using this endpoint with CURL to get lat/long for specific address and it working fine but if i need to get it for 1000 records then needs to make 1000 api call
is there any way i can supply json of address and get the lat/long for 1000 records in one call

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,
```

+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Answer (score 0):

create foreach loop

```
$dataLocations = ["London","Slovakia","Ukraine","Kiev","New York"];

foreach($dataLocations as $location){
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$location;
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($data, true);
return $json;
}
```

Comment: i don't want to make calls through loop plz ready question again

Comment: Then is no way to get 1000 record without 1000 API calls as you said "i can supply json of address and get the lat/long for 1000 records in one call" you have to loop all this 100 records